# disable a text area and a button if a cell in datatable is field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to disable the text field "ICICI BM/DBM EMP_ID" and "APPROVE" Button  in the below code if bank_emp_id is present in database ? Its means if bank_emp_id is present in the database user will not being able to enter any input in the text area and button will remain disabled and if id is not present then the text field and button will remain enable.

Please help as soon as possible.

```
<?php
include 'includes/header.php';




if(htmlspecialchars(isset($_GET['sid'])))
{
$sid=htmlspecialchars($_GET['sid']);
$sql="SELECT * FROM branchdetail WHERE solID= '{$sid}' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ";
$result=mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
?>
<section id="services">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr><th align="center" colspan="6">Park Telesolutions Pvt. Ltd.</th></tr>
                    <tr>
                    <th colspan="3">Corporate Office: BlockAQ, Plot No.-12,Sec-V, Salt Lake, Kolkata-700091</th>
                    <th colspan="3">Registered Office: 9/8, Netaji Nagar, Kolkata-700092</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <th colspan="2">Website:- www.parkgroup.co.in</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Phone No.:- (033)6500 2963/64</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Email:- info@parkgroup.co.in</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><th align="center" colspan="6">Installation & Commissioning Report</th></tr>
                    <tr>
                    <th colspan="1">Sol ID-<?php echo $row['solID']?></th>
                    <th colspan="2">Branch Name-<?php echo $row['branchName']?></th>
                    <th colspan="3">Branch Address-<?php echo $row['branchAddress']?></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="1">SL.NO</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Material Description</th>
                        <th colspan="1">UOM</th>
                        <th colspan="1">BOQ QTY</th>
                        <th colspan="1">Installed QTY</th>
                    </tr>

                    <?php
                    $sql="SELECT * FROM imc WHERE solID= '{$sid}' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
                    $result= mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                     ?>
                     <tr>
                        <th colspan="1">1</th>
                        <th colspan="2"><?php echo $row['camera']?></th>
                        <th colspan="1">NOS</th>
                        <th colspan="1"><?php echo $row['cameraqty']?></th>
                        <th colspan="1"><?php echo $row['cameraqty']?></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="1">2</th>
                        <th colspan="2"><?php echo $row['dvr']?></th>
                        <th colspan="1">NOS</th>
                        <th colspan="1"><?php echo $row['dvrqty']?></th>
                        <th colspan="1"><?php echo $row['dvrqty']?></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="1">3</th>
                        <th colspan="2"><?php echo $row['harddisk']?></th>
                        <th colspan="1">NOS</th>
                        <th colspan="1"><?php echo $row['harddiskqty']?></th>
                        <th colspan="1"><?php echo $row['harddiskqty']?></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="1">4</th>
                        <th colspan="2"><?php echo $row['monitor']?></th>
                        <th colspan="1">NOS</th>
                        <th colspan="1"><?php echo $row['monitorqty']?></th>
                        <th colspan="1"><?php echo $row['monitorqty']?></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="1">5</th>
                        <th colspan="2"><?php echo $row['smps']?></th>
                        <th colspan="1">NOS</th>
                        <th colspan="1"><?php echo $row['smpsqty']?></th>
                        <th colspan="1"><?php echo $row['smpsqty']?></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="1">6</th>
                        <th colspan="2"><?php echo $row['cameracable']?></th>
                        <th colspan="1">Per Mtr.</th>
                        <th colspan="1"><?php echo $row['cameracableqty']?></th>
                        <th colspan="1"><?php echo $row['cameracableqty']?></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="1">7</th>
                        <th colspan="2"><?php echo $row['camerapowercable']?></th>
                        <th colspan="1">Per Mtr.</th>
                        <th colspan="1"><?php echo $row['camerapowercableqty']?></th>
                        <th colspan="1"><?php echo $row['camerapowercableqty']?></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="1">8</th>
                        <th colspan="2"><?php echo $row['conduitpipe']?></th>
                        <th colspan="1">Per Mtr.</th>
                        <th colspan="1"><?php echo $row['conduitpipeqty']?></th>
                        <th colspan="1"><?php echo $row['conduitpipeqty']?></th>
                    </tr>



                    <tr>

                    <th colspan="4">I&C Report No.- <?php echo $row['POno']?></th>
                    <th colspan="2">DATE- <?php echo $row['date']?></th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                    <th colspan="3">PARK Emp_ID- <?php echo $row['park_emp_id']?></th>
                    <th colspan="3">ICICI BM/DBM Emp_ID- <?php echo $row['bank_emp_id']?></th>

                    </tr>
                  <?php
}}}
                   ?> 
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
        </div>
</section>
<div class="col-sm-12">

<form class="" action="" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="comment">ICICI BM/DBM EMP_ID:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bank_emp_id" name="bank_emp_id" required="require" placeholder="Please Enter Your ICICI EMP-ID">
    </div><br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit">Approve</button>
</form>
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 text-right">
    <h4><a href="home.php?solid=<?php echo $sid;?>">Back</a></h4>
</div>

<br><br><br><br>
<?php   
if(htmlspecialchars(!isset($_POST['submit']))){
        //header('Location:create_bmDbm.php');
    }else{

        $bank_emp_id=htmlspecialchars($_POST['bank_emp_id']);
        $sql="UPDATE imc SET bank_emp_id='{$bank_emp_id}'";
        $sql.=" WHERE solID='{$sid}' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";

        $result=mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

        if(!$result){
            echo 'ERROR'.mysqli_error($connection);
        }else{

            header('Location:sensor_detail.php?sid='.$sid.'&bank_emp_id='.$bank_emp_id);
        }
    }

?>
</div>
<?php    include 'includes/footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: you can create two separate view, rather then show/hide input field which leads you security concerns.

Comment: Sir main motive is to stop update database twice. If an user enter emp_id and approve it then it will update the database but next time if the user again login then he/she will again may enter the id and approve it so the database will again get update so if id is present then the text area and approve button will get disabled so that user will not being able to approve it twice.

Comment: Warning! You're open for SQL injection attacks. The function`htmlspecialchars()` is _not_ the correct function to escape the data. You should look into using parameterized prepared statements instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following code
HTML : `<input type="text" onkeyup="checkAvailability(this);" class="form-control" id="bank_emp_id" name="bank_emp_id" required="require" placeholder="Please Enter Your ICICI EMP-ID">`

Jquery/Ajax:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkAvailability(e) {
var check = $("#bank_emp_id").val();
jQuery.ajax({
url: "check.php",
data:'check='+check,
type: "POST",
success:function(data){
if(data=="Exist"){
$("input").attr('disabled',true);
}else{
$("input").attr('disabled',false);
}
},
error:function (){}
});
}
</script>
```

The check.php

```
// include your connection file
if(!empty($_POST['check'])){
$check=$_POST['check'];
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT bank_emp_id FROM your_table_name WHERE bank_emp_id='$check'");
$numrows=mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($numrows > 0){
echo "Exist";
}else{
echo "";
}
}
```